# How to safely bind a foreign key field with a Django ModelForm

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a list of `Foo` objects which I want to render in view. Each `Foo` object has a one to one relationship with a `Bar` object.

My `models.py`:

```
Class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

Class Bar(models.Model):
    foo = models.OneToOneField(Foo, related_name="bar", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    num = models.PositiveInteger(default=0)
```

When I render the `Foo` objects, I want to pass a `BarForm` object for each in order to be able to add or edit the `Bar` object related to the `Foo` object.

My `forms.py`:

```
class BarForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Bar
        fields = ('name', 'num')
```

my `foo_list.html`:

```
{% for foo, bar_form in foo_barform_pairs %}
    <p>{{foo.name}}</p>
    {% include 'bar_form.html' with form=bar_form %}
{% endfor %}
```

The difficulty that I have now is that I don't know how should I include the `foo` foreign key in the `BarForm` (the user should not be able to see, add or change this value) so later when I call `form.save()` the `Bar` object is saved correctly.

My `bar_form.html`:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'submit_bar' %}">
    {{ form.as_p }}
</form>
```

My `views.py`:

```
def index(request):
    foos = Foo.objects.all()
    foo_barform_pairs = []
    for foo in foos:
        foo_barform_pairs.append((foo, BarForm(initial={'name': foo.bar.name, 'num': foo.bar.num})))
    return render(request, 'foo_list.html', {"foo_barform_pairs": foo_barform_pairs}
```